# Value without fraction

Tags: jstl

How can I print a value without fraction? For example:

```
${bites/1024}
```

where `bites` equals to 100000. Output is `97,65625`. I want to print `97` instead.

Comment: Is it possible to do the calculation and formatting before passing in the value?

Comment: Yes, but painfully a bit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with [jstl format](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jstl_format_formatnumber_tag.htm) numbers.

Here's a example.

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" prefix="fmt" %>

<c:set var="bites" value="100000" />
<c:set var="result" value="${bites/1024}"/>
<fmt:formatNumber value="${result-(result%1)}" pattern="#"></fmt:formatNumber>

pattern="#" - remove decimal places,you can specify your own decimal places if you want.
n-(n%1) - equation result to floor value.
```

Or with combination of substring in [jstl functions](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jstl_function_substring.htm).

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" prefix="fmt" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" prefix="fn" %>


<fmt:formatNumber value="${fn:substring(bites/1024, 0, 3)}" type="NUMBER"></fmt:formatNumber>
```